# How do I restrict files (SQLite3 DB, etc.) from being deleted until the Python program is running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, file-management, rights

I am working on a small python3 project which is a TKinter GUI program, how I can restrict users from deleting the associated files like sqlite3 DB, templates, html etc. until the python script is running. I tried some solution of locking the file into read only which restricts users to delete files but same time it became Un useful for my python script.
Is there any way i can keep the file read/write for python script but read only for user who is using the program so files cannot be removed.

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question, but hidden files could be helpful for you. When a file is hidden, you can usually only see it if you enable a setting. On Windows there's a 'hidden' attribute on files, and on Unix (including Linux and macOS), filenames with a dot at the start (e.g. `.important-data`) are generally not shown.

Comment: Onto which OS are you planning to deploy the UI?

Comment: If using *nix, [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/648574) might be a viable option.  Aside, the user permissions can be set such that a file cannot be modified (deleted) by unauthorised users.

Comment: @S3DEV, it will deploy in windows

Comment: I’m afraid the more straight forward option will be as already suggested, making them hidden files.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm looking for a more stringent way

Answer (score 0):

If you open files with `with open()`, they will be marked as "used" by `Python`, and you can't delete them.

Example:

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    with open(r".\fox.txt"):
        await asyncio.sleep(1000)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: It would not be a good idea as with open() cannot be used for DB files for example.